# how to add an Enter key event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
btnSend.addEventListener('click', async(event)=>{

    event.preventDefault()
    let userInput = txtInput.value;

let temp = `<div class="out-msg">
<span class="my-msg">${userInput}</span>
<img src="static/img/me.jpeg" class="picture">
</div>`;

chatWindow.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", temp);
txtInput.value = ''
    scrollSmoothlyToBottom()
    txtInput.value = '';

   const botResponse = await chatBotChat(userInput)

                    let tempBot = `<div class="out-msgbot">
                    <img src="static/img/bot.jpeg" class="picture">
                    <span class="my-msg">${botResponse}</span>
                    </div>`;

                    chatWindow.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tempBot);
                     scrollSmoothlyToBottom()

})
```

this is from my .html file

```
<form class="popup-chat" action="">
        <div class="title">Virtual Assitant</div>
        <div class="badge">!</div>
        <div class="chat-window" id="chat-window">
            <div class="bot-msg">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/bot.jpeg')}}" alt="" class="picture">
                <span class="msg">Hi, How can i help you?</span>
            </div>
            <p id="scrollv"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="input-area" id="input-area">
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="msg" id="txtInput"/>
            <button id="btn-emoji">&#127773;</button>
            <button class="btn-send"> <i class="material-icons">send</i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How should i add an enter key listerner to this code?

I could only send a message by clicking on the submit button. Thanks for the help. im a beginner.

Comment: `inputElement.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => { if (event.key === "Enter") { /* Do your enter key stuff here */ } })`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps to you.

```js
document.onkeydown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      //Add your Enter event code here, like this.
      alert('Hi, Insert what you want to run here');
    }
}
```